# Auto-save output of function

Tags: r

I've written a simple function that takes two arguments, the table (as file) and the column the address is saved in (as address), geocodes it, and appends the lat/long to the table. It looks like this:

```
geocode<- function(file, address)
     {for(i in 1:length(file[,address]))
 {
 tempfile <- street2coordinates(as.character(file[i,address]))
 file$lat <- tempfile$latitude
 file$lon <- tempfile$longitude
 }
 file
 }
```

This works nicely, except I'd like it to auto-save the output to the file.  I can get it to do that by running

```
file <- geocode(file, address)
```

but I'd like it to just autosave.  I'm sure this is a daft question, and yes, I can just point the output of the function back at the data table but I'd like to reduce steps (this will be the start of a chained function). any help appreciated

Comment: Ideally, your function wouldn't need to overwrite the entire `file` anyway, since you're just adding a couple of columns. If you just return the `latitude` and `longitude` from your function instead, you can add the new columns as a step in your chain of operations.

Comment: go on? functionally (pun not intended) I thought I'd done exactly that.

Comment: You'll have to call the function at some later point anyways no? So just rewrite the dataframe there?

Comment: I mean, fair enough, just trying to reduce key strokes since I'm looking to chain this into another function

Comment: @ike - Nope, you return `file` at the end of your function. You could return `list(latitude, longitude)` or `cbind(latitude,longitude)` instead. I am assuming you are using dplyr or something to chain? So you could do `file %>% bind_rows(., geocode(address) )` or something similar. (I rarely use dplyr so that code may or may not be actually working.